# How can I calculate the values entered in edittext and transfer from one activity to another?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am devoloping a roof calculater. i have three edittext and calculate button in the first activity. In the second activity i have a textview that shows the result.

```
    EditText editText1Değer1Kod;
    EditText editText2Değer2Kod;
    EditText editText3Değer3Kod;

    Button hesaplaKod;
```

I want to take these three value then calculate with formula then show the result in second activity as a textview.
How can i calculate (sum or add this three value) then show in the second activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in first Activity

```
hesaplaKod.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int value1= Integer.parseInt(EditText01.getText().toString());
                int value2= Integer.parseInt(EditText01.getText().toString());
                int value3= Integer.parseInt(EditText01.getText().toString());

                int add = value1+value2+value3;

                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("AddValue", add);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

And in onCreate of Second Activity get the value from this

```
int addvalue = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("AddValue");
```

Answer (score 1):

`enter code here`just pass calculate the number and pass the using intent to other activity

in First Activity :

```
Intent intent=new Intent(IntentsDemo2.this,Activity2.class);
   intent.putExtra("result", result);
   startActivity(intent);
```

in Second Activity :

@Override

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main2);
         Intent sender=getIntent();
         int result =sender.getExtras().getInt("result");
}
```

Comment: for help basic tute http://revenmerchantservices.com/post/Android-Button-Click.aspx (scroll down to bottom)